# shell search for "<fileprefix>*" not working

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of filenames without file extensions. I want to loop that list and search for every file-prefix and if a file was found then copy it to a location.

Right now my script produces `*2209589` from string `32201069`.
But instead `32201069` should become `32201069*` to the `-name` parameter of `find`!

My problem is, I cant append an `*` asterisk to my names from the file, as "`{$filename}*` seems to override the first character of the filename string instead of appending it.

```sh
while read filename; do
    find . -name "${filename}*" -print \
         -exec cp -n {} /Users/herrsch/Desktop/foundimages \;;
done < /Users/herrsch/Desktop/fileprefixes.txt
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. I can't think of any way that it would change `32201069` to `2209589`.

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible. What exactly is in `fileprefixes.txt`?

Comment: What do you mean by "override the first character of the filename"? How does that relate to the transformation you describe? They're completely different, not just the first character.

Comment: @tripleee my filenames, that i search for always start with 8 digit prefix. These prefixes are inside that file. Each line for each one file prefix..

```32208444\n32201069\n32202955\n...```

Comment: The best hypothesis I can come up with is that the input file is malformed somehow. Can you [edit] the question to include a snippet, perhaps with a hex dump of the first line or two to show that there are no invisible control characters there?

Comment: @tripleee YES! You have been right! It was formated in UTF-8 and CRLF linebreaks "\r\n" - I converted it to LF "\n" and ISO-8859-1 aaand it worked! Thank you so much! I have been days at it..

Comment: Probably keep it in UTF-8 though.